# Android Eclipse jUnit does not see superclass

Tags: android, junit

This may be a simple answer.

1)  Create a jar file with this code:

```
package com.myCompany.base;

public class Dex1 {

    public String getTerm1() {
        return "Term 1";
    }
}
```

This is compiled to Dex1.jar using NetBeans.

2)  Created a 'Hello world' android application in Eclipse.  Add the code for Dex2 that extends Dex1.  Copy and add Dex1.jar to the java build path.

```
package com.myCompany;

import com.myCompany.base.Dex1;

public class Dex2 extends Dex1 {

    public String getTerm2() {
        return getTerm1() + " Term 2";
    }

}
```

in my onCreate() call:

```
editText.setText(dex2.getTerm2());
```

Everything works Great!  I get the correct string displayed on the android screen.  Yea!

Now the problem starts:

3)  Create a jUnit 3 test case using Eclipse command File -> New -> Project -> Android Text Project command and add the code:

```
    package com.myCompany.test;

    import junit.framework.TestCase;

    import com.myCompany.Dex2;

    public class Dex2Test extends TestCase {

        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            dex2 = new Dex2();
        }

        protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
        }

        Dex2 dex2;

        public void testGetTerm2() {
/*line 21 */    assertEquals("Term 1 Term 2", dex2.getTerm2());
        }

        public void testGetTerm1() {
/* line 25 */   assertEquals("Term 1", dex2.getTerm1());  
        }

    }
```

On Line 25 the compiler gives a 'method undefined' error for getTerm1().   I don't understand why this is an error?

I tried to add the Dex1.jar to the java Build path of the test project, it compiles but we receive a run time error 'NoClassDefFoundError'. Yuch!

**More Information 16Mar2012**
I set this up using Plan Java classes, same jar file, to remove Android and it worked.  This makes me conclude there must be some anomaly in Android/DalvikVM (aka DavrosVM).
**More Information 16Mar2012 End**

Am I missing something?
Is the jar file built incorrectly (didn't think that was possible)? 
Am I importing the jar file incorrectly?
Is it just crazy to expect to import and override a class in a jar file?

Thank you for reading, please reply.

Fish

Comment: This is not the normal way we do with Android Test Project. Generally speaking, by running android junit test, there are actually two apk files (app.apk and test.apk) installed and ran on AVD (or real device), coordinate with each other all managed by instrument test runner. Dex2 is defined in main project and dexed within app.apk, which is invisible to either test.apk or instrument test runner's class loader at instrument runtime. Android Test Project is more focusing on testing Android components (Activity, Service etc), not suitable for testing these POJO defined within your main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Android Testing: External libraries](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html) which I guess have the solution to your problem.
What you may be doing wrong is not exporting your library in **Order and Export** under **Java Build Path**.

Comment: I doubt this will work unless you move Dex2 to the jar library. the dependency between Android Project and Android Test Project is not on code level (i.e. import a class from Android project, then instantiate  an object of that type from scratch within Test project), it is resolved at instrument runtime (i.e. all objects you are going to instrument in Test Project are instantiated when test runner run your app), in a word, the relationship between Android Project and Android Test Project is not bound at compile time, it is bound at instrument runtime.

Comment: dtMilano,  your answer was correct.   Thanks,  btw I ordered your book.